# How to run VMWare and VirtualBox on OSX with Bridged Networking

Tags: networking, macos, virtualbox, vmware-fusion, bridged

So here's the issue. I'm running OSX Mavericks as host OS.

I've had VirtualBox for a while, and I typically use bridged networking for the VMs I run on Vbox. Had no problems there. I recently installed VMWare as my company has licenses and I needed a VM which they were only willing to provide me in VMWare format.

Now I have VMWare and VirtualBox installed. VMWare everything works fine, but VirtualBox bridged networking does not work at all. However I can switch to NAT on VirtualBox and it still works, but I'd really like to have bridged networking.

Doing ifconfig, I'm pretty sure there's some stuff there that was not before installing VMWare, but I'm not really a networking expert so I don't know why only bridged networking doesn't work with vbox anymore.